# such like doing? and the use of the word "earn"

Tags: word-request, participles

> A may mean an event, or an event's profit such like **earn** 10 dollars in one gambling game.

Is there any problem in using `earning`?

like is an prep and after the present participle?

And in a gambling game, `earn` is not a good word to use here?

Comment: It should be *...such **as earning** $10 in one game*. But mostly you don't "earn" a profit when gambling (except maybe if you're a professional gambler). You ***win*** an amount, or ***make/show*** a profit.

Comment: @FumbleFingers How about the use of `earning` is it good in this situation? Since gambling game is not one formal job?

Comment: No - as I said, *earning* is not a good word for money you *win* at gambling. You *earn **wages*** for doing a ***job***, so unless gambling is your "job", don't use that word.

Answer (score 1):

When referring to gambling, I would use the word **win**, rather than "earn," because it is the result of luck, not skill.

Used as a gerund, one would use the "ing" form; e.g., the event of "winn **ing** $10..."

Comment: Dee-lightful. Apropos, do you know Twain's ["Science vs. Luck"](http://www.twainquotes.com/Galaxy/187010d.html)?